# How to use a Cisco 880

Tags: wireless-networking, login, adsl, cisco-router

I just bought a Cisco 800 series (a router) and I logged into the web panel and I don't know how to enable the Wi-Fi. The Wi-Fi panel is just empty with a info sign saying 'Click here to open the wireless screen in a new browser tab'. I click it and It asks me to login so I do and it keeps on to open the login in Chrome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### I don't know how to enable the Wi-Fi

> The wireless device is embedded and does not have an external console port for connections. To
> configure the wireless device, use a console cable to connect a personal computer to the host router’s
> console port, and perform these procedures to establish connectivity and configure the wireless settings
>
> - Starting a Wireless Configuration Session, page 4-2
> - Closing the Session, page 4-3
> - Configuring Wireless Settings, page 4-4
> - Configuring the Access Point in Hot Standby Mode, page 4-9 (Optional)
>
> ...

Source: https://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/access/800/880/software/configuration/guide/SCG_880_series.pdf